# Writing equations in Tex

Tags: latex, tex

I am writing my first scientific paper, and unfortunately have a (very slow) windows PC. I had installed some packages from the Tex website some time ago, one of which is 'Tex desktop app'. It seems to be a word processor, and I have started writing things using this. However I cannot seem to insert an equation. There is certainly no icon for equations, and I have tried `$...$`, `$\latex...$`, `\latex...`

However my equations are not being formatted. the '\latex' is, however, color coded blue. So at least it is recognized by the program.

Does anyone know if 'Tex desktop app' is a suitable word processor to use for writing papers? If so, how do I write equations in it? Does anyone have any better suggestions for packages for writing papers that my already-pathetically-slow Windows laptop may be able to handle? I am getting very confused with all of the 'Tex' packages and what they are for...

Comment: I would suggest you to look also at https://www.sharelatex.com/ you just need to register and then you have access to most of the latex libraries automatically. I wrote a paper with this tool, but maybe, just don't write there a document where you prove that P != NP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to start off by looking at the advice in the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-TeXsystems).  I don't use Windows, but my impression is that MikTeX is *the* LaTeX editor and processor for Windows.  TeX is quite an old program, so you should be able to find an environment which runs acceptably even on an ancient Windows machine.

The [TeX stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com) is a good place for both beginner and advanced LaTeX questions.